# Is this integration by parts wrong or right?

Tags: calculus, integration

Integrate $\int{x^2 \ln x\, dx}$

Let $u = \ln x,\ v = x^2$
$du = 1/x\, dx$

$uv - \int v\, du$

$x^2 \ln x - \int (x^2) (1/x)\, dx$

$x^2 \ln x - (x^2)/2 + C$

Comment: yeah sorry messed up a bit. thanks for the tip anyway

Comment: So, if you understand it now, Zhi, can you write up and post an answer?

Comment: Are you still here?

Answer (score 0):

$$
    \int x^{2}\ln x = \int \frac{1}{3}\frac{d x^{3}}{dx}\ln x\,dx \\
           = \frac{x^{3}}{3}\ln x -\int \frac{x^{3}}{3}\frac{1}{x}\,dx \\
           = \frac{x^{3}}{3}\ln x -\frac{x^{3}}{9}+C. 
$$
It never hurts to check:
$$
  \frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{x^{3}}{3}\ln x-\frac{x^{3}}{9}+C\right] \\
   = \left(x^{2}\ln x + \frac{x^{3}}{3}\frac{1}{x}\right)-\frac{x^{2}}{3} \\
   = x^{2}\ln x.
$$